# Navbar transition not working in tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

```
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false)

    const toggleNavItems = () => {
        setShowNav(!showNav)
    }
    console.log(showNav)

 <ul className="sm:hidden">
                <li className="px-2 md:px-4" onClick={toggleNavItems}>
                    <div className="text-purple-600 font-semibold hover:text-purple-500 text-3xl cursor-pointer">
                        <FaBars />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
       
            <div className={`overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 ease-in ${showNav ? 'block absolute w-full top-[60px] right-0' : "hidden"}`}>
                <ul>
                    <li className='p-4'>
                        <Link to={'/'} className='text-purple-600 font-semibold hover:text-purple-500'>
                            {" "}
                            Home{" "}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I am trying to set the `showNav` with some transition properties while clicking the button. However, even I added the related classes, the items just appeared without any transition properties. May I ask how to have transitions working properly?

I followed thoroughly the documentation of tailwind CSS but there are no any effects.

Comment: Transitions don't work as you expect on the 'display' prop. You should use properties like 'opacity' or 'height' if you want transitions (there are others I don't have on thop of my mind rn)

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guy said: You can't animate `hidden`.

I recommend you use something like `translate-y-full` and `translate-y-0` to animate the navbar. If that's not the look you're going for absolutely go for opacity.

Comment: So how can I animate from hidden to displaying on website?

Comment: You can't. That's what we are saying. You can animate something like height, opacity, translate etc. Did you really read our answers?

Comment: I changed to visibility and opacity properties and it works now